# loading data to jquery datatables using the selection of another datatable and Django

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, datatables

I have a few tables on a page in a Django application and I am using Datatables to view, search and sort the data.

If a row of one datatable, the customers table, is selected by the user I send the ID of this row using AJAX to a view in my views.py file. What I want to happen now is that a second table, the visits table, is updated with the relevant visits for this customer. I know that the data is sent correctly and the Django query I create is correct as I can print out the visits object to the Django console. But I am struggling with what to do with the data now.

Usually I would render a template using this data as a context, and in fact this is how I generated the customer table. But I think I need to send it back to the client side and let the Datatable do the rendering? Both tables are on the same page so I want to just render the updated visits table.

Here is a snippet of my Javascript file

```
var cust_table = $('#all_customers').DataTable({"lengthMenu": [3],
                                               "bLengthChange": false,
                                               "paging": true,
                                                select: 'single'});
$('#all_visits').DataTable({"lengthMenu": [3],
                            "bLengthChange": false})

cust_table.on('select', function (e, dt, type, indexes) {
      var rowData = pt_table.rows(indexes).data().toArray()[0][0]; 
      var URL = 'select_customer/';
      var id = { 'id': rowData };
      $.get(URL, id,  function (response) {
          if (response === 'success') {alert("success");}
          else {alert("error");
          }
    });
```

and this is the view that processes the request

```
def select_customer(request):

"""
Use the customer id selected by the user to fill the visits table.
"""
try:
    if request.method == "GET":
        print "request has come through"
        if "id" in request.GET:
            visits = (CustomerId.objects.get(id=request.GET["id"])
                      .customer.visit_set.all()
            context = {"visits": visits}
            render(request, 'flair_app/patients/visit_table.html', context)
except:
    return HttpResponse('fail')
```

As I said, I can print out the visits object on the Django console so I know they are there. But trying to render the visit_table template, which just contains the table doesn't change the page.

I am quite new to web development so apologies if this is an easy question; but how do I display the data on the page?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting back an HTML string from the server. But on the client, you only receive it in your `response` variable, but then you don't do anythong with it.

You need to inject it into the HTML of the page if you want to to render.

Assuming that `flair_app/patients/visit_table.html` is only the HTML for the `#all_visits` table, you could simply replace the current HTML in that element with the HTML that was returned by the server. Something like this

```
$.get(URL, id)
.done(function(responseData) {
    $('#all_visits').html(responseData);
})
.fail(function(error){
    // handle error
});
```

After that, you will probably need to rebind you `DataTable` objects again

```
$('#all_visits').DataTable({"lengthMenu": [3], "bLengthChange": false})
```

Comment: Thanks C14L for your help. Ive changed the return statement on the view method to HttpResponse(visits) and I've changed the visits data format to json. In Chrome developer tools I can see the data as it is returned to the client side. So I will work on getting it to display in the datatable.